# Finding the Maclaurin series of a rational function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

**Question: Find the Maclaurin series of the following function: $\frac{z}{z^2-4z+13}$**

**My attempt:**

I tried to do this by converting it into a geometric series. Would this be correct?

$$\frac{z}{z^2-4z+13} = \frac{1}{z-4+\frac{13}{z}}= (-4)(\frac{1}{1 -(\frac{z}{4}+\frac{13}{4z})})$$

Which would then be a geometric series? I can't think of any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Do not divide by $z$ since you want to build a series around $z=0$.*

For sure, you could build the Maclaurin  from definition but the high order derivatives would be quite tedious to establish.

One possible way is to consider$$f=\frac{z}{z^2-4z+13}=\frac z {13}\times\frac 1{1-\big(\frac 4{13}z-\frac 1{13}z^2\big)}$$ Set $t=\big(\frac 4{13}z-\frac 1{13}z^2\big)$. So $$f=\frac z {13}\times\frac 1{1-t}=\frac z {13}\times\sum_{i=0}^\infty t^i=\frac z {13}\times\sum_{i=0}^\infty \big(\frac 4{13}z-\frac 1{13}z^2\big)^i$$ and use the binomial theorem up to the order you need. Limited to the fifth order (I am lazy), this should give $$f=\frac{1}{13}z+\frac{4 }{169}z^2+\frac{3 }{2197}z^3-\frac{40 }{28561}z^4-\frac{199
   }{371293}z^5+O\left(z^6\right) $$ and you will recognize that the denominators of the coefficients are the successive powers of $13$.

Another solution could have been the long division of $z$ by $13-4z+z^2$.

**Edit**

You could make life easier setting from the beginning $z=13x$; so $$f=\frac{x}{1-4x+13 x^2}$$ and now, setting $t=(4x-13x^2)$ $$f=x\times\sum_{i=0}^\infty (4x-13x^2)^i$$

Answer (score 0):

I would procede like this : $$\frac{z}{z^2-4z+13} = \frac{z}{(z-2)^2+9} =\frac{z}{(z-2-3i)(z-2+3i)}.$$ Then a decomposition $$\frac{z}{(z-2-3i)(z-2+3i)} = \frac{iz}{6} \left(\frac{1}{z-2-3i} - \frac{1}{z-2+3i} \right)$$ leads to the conclusion since you know the MacLaurin series for the two terms.

Comment: Sorry, is my answer correct? And also what are the maclaurin series for the two terms?

Comment: Well, it is correct yes. (But note that you introduced a removable singularity at $z=0$) However you will probably have some difficulties to get the final answer, because you will have to develop $\sum (\frac{z}{4}+\frac{13}{4z})^n.$ The series for $\frac{1}{z-2-3i} = \frac{-1}{2+3i}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{2+3i}}$ is much easier. This is a simple geometric series.

Comment: I see! That makes sense! Also for the geometric series to hold, $\lvert r \rvert  \le 1$ so does that mean the radius of convergence is $R \le 2+3i$?

Comment: A little correction. Your method is actually false because $|(\frac{z}{4}+\frac{13}{4z})|$ is not $<1$ when $z$ is in a small disk centered at the origin. Thus you can't apply geometric series.

Comment: Thank you for that! Am I correct in my radius of convergence assumption?

Comment: You must have $|\frac{z}{2+3i}| <1$, hence $|z| < \sqrt{13}.$ (A radius must be real not complex, you forgot the modul for $2+3i$.)